# How to create the library from react-native app and all .tsx and .js files should be present inside the library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have used the "npx react-native-create-library libname" in the existing application for creating the library but it's removing all the .tsx and .js file from that, but i want to use those, how it will be possible...?

just expecting the library available with all .tsx and .js files.